# Selenium Not Scraping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to come up with a way to scrape data from [this site](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/institutional-holdings) but the code won't scrape any value.

[image]

```
import csv
import os
os.getcwd()
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


options = Options()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'insert path here')

completeurl = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/MSFT/institutional-holdings'


driver.get(completeurl)
time.sleep(10)
increased_positions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]')
print(increased_positions.text)

driver.quit()
```

This code is throwing an error.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way to accomplish the task and you can get all the required tables from the list of dataframes:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'insert path here')

driver.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/institutional-holdings")
html = driver.page_source
tables = pd.read_html(html)
data = tables[1]
data
driver.quit()
```